# Contact Form 7 Responsive Email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a responsive email template that I want to send after people fill out my form. It works: the response I get back is laid out correctly - it just isn't responsive. I know it works just can't figure it out in Contact For 7.

There is a problem with the @media screen at the top of the email: it displays a ton of code at the top of the email after it gets sent.

This is my code:

```
  <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Webmaster Services Hawaii</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <style type="text/css">
 /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
 #outlook a {
 padding: 0;
 } /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
 .ReadMsgBody {
 width: 100%;
 }
 .ExternalClass {
 width: 100%;
 } /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
 .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
 line-height: 100%;
 } /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
 body, table, td, a {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 } /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
 table, td {
 mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
 mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
 } /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
 img {
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
 } /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
 /* RESET STYLES */
 body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }
 img {
 border: 0;
 height: auto;
 line-height: 100%;
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 table {
 border-collapse: collapse !important;
 }
 body {
 height: 100% !important;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
     width: 100% !important;
 }
 /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
 .appleBody a {
 color: #68440a;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
 .appleFooter a {
 color: #999999;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

/* MOBILE STYLES */
 @media screen and (max-width: 525px) {
 /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
 table[class="wrapper"] {
 width: 100% !important;
 }
 /* ADJUSTS LAYOUT OF LOGO IMAGE */
 td[class="logo"] {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 20px 0 20px 0 !important;
 }
 td[class="logo"] img {
 margin: 0 auto!important;
 }
 /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
 td[class="mobile-hide"] {
 display: none;
 }
 img[class="mobile-hide"] {
 display: none !important;
 }
 img[class="img-max"] {
 max-width: 100% !important;
 height: auto !important;
 }
 /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
 table[class="responsive-table"] {
 width: 100%!important;
 }
 /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */
 td[class="padding"] {
 padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
 }
 td[class="padding-copy"] {
 padding: 10px 5% 10px 5% !important;
 text-align: center;
 }
 td[class="padding-meta"] {
 padding: 30px 5% 0px 5% !important;
 text-align: center;
 }
 td[class="no-pad"] {
 padding: 0 0 20px 0 !important;
 }
 td[class="no-padding"] {
 padding: 0 !important;
 }
 td[class="section-padding"] {
 padding: 50px 15px 50px 15px !important;
 }
 td[class="section-padding-bottom-image"] {
 padding: 50px 15px 0 15px !important;
 }
 /* ADJUST BUTTONS ON MOBILE */
 td[class="mobile-wrapper"] {
 padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
 }
 table[class="mobile-button-container"] {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100% !important;
 }
 a[class="mobile-button"] {
 width: 80% !important;
 padding: 15px !important;
 border: 0 !important;
 font-size: 16px !important;
 }
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

<!-- HEADER -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><div align="center" style="padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="wrapper">
 <!-- LOGO/PREHEADER TEXT -->
 <tr>
 <td style="padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;" class="logo"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100" align="left"><img alt="Logo" src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/wp-filessystem/uploads/2015/03/supersmall4.png" style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px;" border="0"></td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="400" align="right" class="mobile-hide"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
 <td align="right" style="padding: 0 0 5px 0; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">We offer everything you need to have a successful online presence </span></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<!-- ONE COLUMN SECTION -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 70px 15px 70px 15px;" class="section-padding"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table">
 <tr>
 <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td><!-- HERO IMAGE -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
     <tr>
 <td class="padding-copy"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td><img src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/newsletter/images/Ecommerce_SEO_Tips_Shopify_Shopping_Cart_Software_Blog_1.jpg" width="500" height="200" border="0" alt="Can an email really be responsive?" style="display: block; padding: 0; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 500px; height: 200px;" class="img-max"></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><!-- COPY -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; padding-top: 30px;" class="padding-copy">$395. Yes *|FNAME|* you can afford QUALITY SEO Services in Hawaii!
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">We offer everything you need to have a successful online presence especially here in Hawaii! Through our proven marketing strategies, you'll turn visitors into leads, leads into customers, and customers into advocates of your brand. </td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><!-- BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-button-container">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding: 25px 0 0 0;" class="padding-copy"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="responsive-table">
 <tr>
 <td align="center">Learn How →</td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<!-- ONE COLUMN W/ BOTTOM IMAGE SECTION -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" align="center" style="padding: 70px 15px 0 15px;" class="section-padding-bottom-image"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table">
 <tr>
 <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td><!-- COPY -->

table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333;" class="padding-copy">Mobile opens are up 48%!</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">With an increasingly mobile audience, can you really afford to not have your website mobile responsive?</td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
     <tr>
 <td><!-- BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-button-container">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding: 25px 0 0 0;" class="padding-copy"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="responsive-table">
 <tr>
 <td align="center">Heck No →</td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><!-- BOTTOM IMAGE -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td style="padding: 50px 0 0 0;" align="center"><img src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/newsletter/images/line-graph.jpg" width="500" height="180" border="0" alt="Mobile opens are on the rise" class="img-max" style="display: block; padding: 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; width: 500px; height: 180px;"></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<!-- TWO COLUMN SECTION -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 70px 15px 70px 15px;" class="section-padding"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table">
 <tr>
 <td><!-- TITLE SECTION AND COPY -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333;" class="padding-copy">How does it work?</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 20px 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666;" class="padding-copy">Your website is the starting point of SEO services. The climb to the top in search results starts with on page optimization and gains momentum with off page SEO optimization, a rather convoluted and time consuming process akin to growing a tree and then harvesting fruits of hard labor for years. These two services are crucial if you want high volume of targeted traffic over time.</td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><!-- TWO COLUMNS -->

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td valign="top" style="padding: 0;" class="mobile-wrapper"><!-- LEFT COLUMN -->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
 <tr>
 <td style="padding: 20px 0 40px 0;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="middle"><img src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/newsletter/images/seo-services.jpg" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; " alt="Fluid images" border="0" class="img-max"></td>
 </tr><tr>
 <td align="center">Learn How →</td>
 </tr>

</table></td></tr> 

</table></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
 <tr>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" align="left" class="responsive-table">
 <tr> </tr>
 </table>
</tr>
</table>
</tr>
    </table>

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <center>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="canspamBarWrapper" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top:1px solid #E5E5E5;">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="canspamBar">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#606060; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:150%; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; text-align:center;">
This email was sent to *|EMAIL|*

why did I get this?    unsubscribe from this list    update subscription preferences

*|LIST:ADDRESSLINE|*

*|REWARDS|*
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
table[id="canspamBar"] td{font-size:14px !important;}
table[id="canspamBar"] td a{display:block !important; margin-top:10px !important;}
}
</style>
</center></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You tell more better? So that i can help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside Contact Form 7: chances are good your template needs to be inlined because email clients strip HEAD tags.

[Common HTML Mistakes](http://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/common-html-mistakes)

```
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width: 525px) {
  table[class="wrapper"] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  td[class="logo"] {
    text-align: left; padding: 20px 0 20px 0 !important;
  }
  td[class="logo"] img {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
  }
  td[class="mobile-hide"] {
    display: none;
  }
  img[class="mobile-hide"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  img[class="img-max"] {
    max-width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;
  }
  table[class="responsive-table"] {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  td[class="padding"] {
    padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
  }
  td[class="padding-copy"] {
    padding: 10px 5% 10px 5% !important; text-align: center;
  }
  td[class="padding-meta"] {
    padding: 30px 5% 0px 5% !important; text-align: center;
  }
  td[class="no-pad"] {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0 !important;
  }
  td[class="no-padding"] {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  td[class="section-padding"] {
    padding: 50px 15px 50px 15px !important;
  }
  td[class="section-padding-bottom-image"] {
    padding: 50px 15px 0 15px !important;
  }
  td[class="mobile-wrapper"] {
    padding: 10px 5% 15px 5% !important;
  }
  table[class="mobile-button-container"] {
    margin: 0 auto; width: 100% !important;
  }
  a[class="mobile-button"] {
    width: 80% !important; padding: 15px !important; border: 0 !important; font-size: 16px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  table[id="canspamBar"] td {
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
  table[id="canspamBar"] td a {
    display: block !important; margin-top: 10px !important;
  }
}
</style>

<!-- HEADER -->
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><div align="center" style="padding: 0px 15px;">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="wrapper" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<!-- LOGO/PREHEADER TEXT --><tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 20px 0px 30px;" class="logo"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><img alt="Logo" src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/wp-filessystem/uploads/2015/03/supersmall4.png" style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 16px; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border: 0;" border="0"></td>
 <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="400" align="right" class="mobile-hide" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td align="right" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0 0 5px;"><span style="color: #666666; text-decoration: none;">We offer everything you need to have a successful online presence </span></td>
 </tr></table></td>
 </tr></table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div></td>
 </tr></table>
<!-- ONE COLUMN SECTION --><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 70px 15px;" class="section-padding"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- HERO IMAGE -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tbody><tr>
<td class="padding-copy" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><img src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/newsletter/images/Ecommerce_SEO_Tips_Shopify_Shopping_Cart_Software_Blog_1.jpg" width="500" height="200" border="0" alt="Can an email really be responsive?" style="display: block; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; width: 500px; height: 200px; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; line-height: 100%; outline: none; padding: 0; border: 0;" class="img-max"></td>
 </tr></table></td>
 </tr></tbody></table>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- COPY -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; padding-top: 30px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" class="padding-copy">$395. Yes *|FNAME|* you can afford QUALITY SEO Services in Hawaii!
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 20px 0 0;" class="padding-copy">We offer everything you need to have a successful online presence especially here in Hawaii! Through our proven marketing strategies, you'll turn visitors into leads, leads into customers, and customers into advocates of your brand. </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-button-container" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 25px 0 0;" class="padding-copy"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">Learn How →</td>
 </tr></table></td>
 </tr></table>
</td>
 </tr>
</table></td>
 </tr></table></td>
 </tr></table>
<!-- ONE COLUMN W/ BOTTOM IMAGE SECTION --><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td bgcolor="#f8f8f8" align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 70px 15px 0;" class="section-padding-bottom-image"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr><td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- COPY -->

table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"&gt;
 </td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" class="padding-copy">Mobile opens are up 48%!</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 20px 0 0;" class="padding-copy">With an increasingly mobile audience, can you really afford to not have your website mobile responsive?</td>
 </tr>
</table></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- BULLETPROOF BUTTON -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-button-container" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 25px 0 0;" class="padding-copy"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">Heck No →</td>
 </tr></table></td>
 </tr></table>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- BOTTOM IMAGE -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 50px 0 0;" align="center"><img src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/newsletter/images/line-graph.jpg" width="500" height="180" border="0" alt="Mobile opens are on the rise" class="img-max" style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; width: 500px; height: 180px; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; padding: 0; border: 0;"></td>
 </tr></table>
</td>
 </tr>
</table></td>
 </tr></table>
<!-- TWO COLUMN SECTION --><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 70px 15px;" class="section-padding"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- TITLE SECTION AND COPY -->

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" class="padding-copy">How does it work?</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 20px 0;" class="padding-copy">Your website is the starting point of SEO services. The climb to the top in search results starts with on page optimization and gains momentum with off page SEO optimization, a rather convoluted and time consuming process akin to growing a tree and then harvesting fruits of hard labor for years. These two services are crucial if you want high volume of targeted traffic over time.</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
<!-- TWO COLUMNS -->

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td valign="top" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0;" class="mobile-wrapper">
<!-- LEFT COLUMN -->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" align="left" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr><td style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 20px 0 40px;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="middle" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><img src="http://www.webmasterserviceshawaii.com/newsletter/images/seo-services.jpg" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; border: 0;" alt="Fluid images" border="0" class="img-max"></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">Learn How →</td>
 </tr>
</table></td></tr></table>
</td>
 </tr></table>
</td>
 </tr>
</table></td>
 </tr>
<tr><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="47%" align="left" class="responsive-table" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr></tr></table></tr></table></tr>
</table>
<!-- FOOTER --><center>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="canspamBarWrapper" style="border-top-color: #E5E5E5; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; background: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="canspamBar" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important;"><tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="color: #606060; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 150%; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 20px; text-align: center; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
This email was sent to *|EMAIL|*

why did I get this?    unsubscribe from this list    update subscription preferences

*|LIST:ADDRESSLINE|*

*|REWARDS|*
    </td>
</tr></table>
</td>
</tr></table>
</center>
</body>
```